# How do I write a MATLAB program to create an image with three basic primary colors in equilateral triangle?

Tags: matlab

It should be in the form of circle with colors inside. The row and columns of spatial positions should define the (x,y) pixel positions for mapping the color coordinates. Any ideas?

[image: for example]

Answer (score 0):

what you want is just the HS colorspace where V=1 ([HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV)), you can use hsv2rgb after generating the `h`, `s`, and `v`:

```
[xg,yg] = meshgrid(linspace(-1,1,1000));
% h is polar, s is radial
[h,s] = cart2pol(xg,yg);
% v is 1 inside the circle and 0 outside
v = double(s <= 1);
% normalize h to [0 1]
h = h/(2*pi) + 0.5;
% convert to rgb
rgb = hsv2rgb(cat(3,h,s,v));
imshow(rgb)
```

[image]

you can further rotate the `h` (add constant and modolue `2*pi`) to rotate the circle.